# background is gone when

Tags: android, performance, smooth-scrolling

I want my application will be more smoothly and I read that `hardware_acceleraton` could be a solution.

So I turn on `hardware_acceleraton = true` and my background image just gone and only appearing black background.

Do I have to do another thing or what is wrong here?

Comment: Real device or is this in the emulator?

Comment: real device Galaxy nexus

Comment: Check out the documentation.  It seems you are having the problems they mention in the 2nd paragraph: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @RickFalck what you mean by 2nd paragraph?

Comment: Where it says "Problems usually manifest themselves......"

Answer (score 1):

When you enable hardware accelaration android uses 'hardware accelerated' implementations of graphics classes like `Canvas` and `Paint`. Each graphics class has two implementations. One that internally uses Skia library (the one that is used when hardware acceleration is disable) and another one which uses OpenGL. Some of the methods of the hardware accelerated implementations are STILL not implemented correctly. For example using a blur or emboss filter on a `Pain` doesn't work. Hardware acceleration is safe to use only with views from android library like `ListView` and `ImageView`. Your problem might be a consequence of enableing hardware acceleration on a custom view.

Comment: There is no any solution here? I am using it custom view. when background set as color it works fine, but when it is image not fine

Comment: If enabling hardware acceleration is essential you can draw the image in the custom view's onDraw() method instead of setting it as a background drawable.

Answer (score -1):

maybe  setting `webView.setBackgroundColor(0) or webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));` 
could help that a little hack but not the best solution i think this work for API less than 11 for higher i think its `webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

exemple:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
setContentView(webView);
```